# Main thread calls methods of another thread - what exactly is happening here?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am kind of confused what is going on when the main user thread calls a sequence of methods in another thread like this

In main thread:

```
otherThread.callMethod();
otherThread.callMethod();
otherThread.callMethod();
otherThread.callMethod();
otherThread.callMethod();
otherThread.callMethod();
otherThread.callMethod();
```

And `callMethod` in the other thread is writing and reading from sockets like this:

```
mmOutStream.write(buffer);
mmOutStream.flush();
while (!finished) {
   if (mmInStream.available() > 0)
   if ((char) (c = (byte) mmInStream.read()) != 'x') {
      responseBuffer[responseBufferLen++] = c;
     } else {
      finished = true;
    }
}
```

This clearly is a blocking scenario - but while these methods are called in sequence, the main user thread is not blocked.

I mean blocked in the sence that all the buttons still react, user can interact with the screen without any delay.
How can that be?

Comment: There is no blocking here, because you are calling available(), which tells you whether a byte can be read *without blocking.* The only blocking that *might* occur is in write() and flush().

Comment: @EJP: but it's even worse, because if nothing is available, there is a busy loop checking if some byte is available constantly.

Comment: "busy loop" - not really, I have a timer around this which acts as a timeout

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Methods are not called on threads. They're called on objects (or on classes, for static methods). An object could be of type `Thread`, but calling a method on an object of type `Thread` is exactly the same as calling a method on an object of any other type. The method is still executed by the current thread.

Comment: but why doesn't my app lock the main user thread then?

Comment: You just provided one line of code, so it's impossible to say what your code does.

Comment: What is the 'main user thread'?

Comment: I added the code of the "other thread" above. The main user thread is the screen that is currently visible which is a SherlockFragmentActivity. The exact same code on iPhone blocks the user screen - for example the button that is pushed on iPhone stays pushed until everything is executed - on Android the main screen remains active

Comment: If this blocking sequence of instructions is executed in a thread which is not the UI thread, why would the UI thread be blocked. That's the whole point of threads: being able to execute parallel sequences of instructions. The above sequence is blocked, but the sequence of instructions in the UI thread is not, because they execute in parallel.

Comment: Screens aren't threads. Threads are threads. Unless you are calling those methods on the event-dispatching thread, e.g. in an actionPerformed() callback, there is no reason to expect the GUI to be blocked.

Comment: I think I understand now - but why does it block on iPhone then? These instructions are executed in the main UI thread in Android and iPhone exactly the same...

Comment: Maybe because in the iPhone code, these blocking instructions are not executed in a separate thread, but in the UI thread? I don't know iPhone development at all.

Comment: Thanks very much - I see there is a basic difference between UI thread in Android and on iPhone! - the blocking instructions are executed in another thread on iPhone too. Anyway thanks alot for the clarification!

Answer (score 2):

Threads don't have methods. Classes have methods, and instances. The code is calling instance methods via an object. It all executes in the current thread. The fact that the object is a thread makes no difference.